# How to draw ggmap with two different administrative boundaries?

Tags: r, ggmap

I am wondering how to draw a map using `get_map` and `ggmap` of any federal country (i.e. a country with provinces and counties). Any country, other than the US would be great. To make it look nice, fill the `geom_polygon` of counties (any fill), and provinces are empty polygons, only with its contours. So, basically, it is two overlapping ggmaps.

You can get the shapefiles here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nl685t860x1e8r/municipios_br.zip

```
rm(list = ls())
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(ggmap)

# READ SHAPEFILE OF BOUNDARIES
Map <- readShapePoly("municipios_br.shp")

head(as.data.frame(Map))
Map = gBuffer(Map, width=0, byid=TRUE)
MapC <- fortify(Map, region="CODIGO_MUN") # municipalities
MapP <- fortify(Map, region="CODIGO_UF") # state boundaries
MapC$test <- 1
MapP$test <- 1
MapC <- Map[order(MapC$order),]
MapP <- MapP[order(MapP$order),]
```

The following code produces counties boundaries:

```
google.map <- get_map(location = 'Brazil', zoom=4,maptype="terrain")
m0 <- ggmap(google.map)
m1 <- m0 + geom_polygon(color = 'grey90', size = .01, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=as.factor(test)), data=MapC, alpha=.6)
m1 + guides(fill=FALSE) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("red"))
```

[image: Map - counties]

Now, provinces:

```
m2 <- m0 + geom_polygon(color = 'grey50', size = .1, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=as.factor(test)), data=MapP, alpha=.9)
m2 + guides(fill=FALSE) + scale_fill_manual(values=c(NA))
```

[image: Map - provinces]

How to make the two work together?

Comment: Does too need code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: OK,give me a moment. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also get your maps from e.g. [GADM](http://gadm.org/):

```
library(raster)
adm1 <- getData('GADM', country='HUN', level=0)
adm2 <- getData('GADM', country='HUN', level=1)
```

And let us `fortify` those for `ggplot` usage:

```
library(ggplot2)
fadm1 = fortify(adm1)
fadm2 = fortify(adm2)
```

And add as many layers and geoms as you wish:

```
ggplot(fadm1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_path() +
    geom_polygon(data = fadm2, aes(x = long, y = lat), 
                 fill = "green", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_path(data = fadm2, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "blue") + 
    theme_bw()
```

Resulting in:

[image]

---

**Update**: combining your two layers mentioned in the updated questions

```
m0 + geom_polygon(size = .01,
        aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.factor('red')),
        data = MapC,
        alpha = .6) +
    geom_path(color = 'grey50', size = .1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
        data=MapP, alpha=.9) +
    guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I adapted to my code and I am able to use it. However, I am still trying to implement it with ggmap.

Comment: That is it. I could swear I had tried it before, but oh well. Thanks.