# Draw province boundaries in R

Tags: r, spatial, choropleth

I want to draw choropleth map for my report. I have downloaded the data from GADM. I succeed in drawing choropleth map, but when I added the boundaries, something wrong was happen. A lot of blue line are appeared.

My code is:

```
#Read Database
HCM <- read.csv("HCM.csv")

#Load Packages
library(plyr)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(scales)

#Read Map (Map downloaded from GADM)
vie_map1 <- readRDS('VNM_adm1.rds')
vie_map <- fortify(vie_map1, region = "ID_1")

#Draw the map
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = HCM, aes(map_id = ID, fill = WeightRange), 
           map = vie_map) + expand_limits(x = vie_map$long, y = vie_map$lat)
```

[image: I want this]

But when I want to add the boundaries, something wrong is happened (the straight line in blue). The code for adding boundaries is:

```
  # Add the boundaries
 ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = HCM, aes(map_id = ID, fill = WeightRange), 
           map = vie_map) + expand_limits(x = vie_map$long, y = vie_map$lat)+
 geom_path() +
    geom_path(data = vie_map, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "blue") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Please tell me how to fix it (delete the straight line).

[image: I got this]

Comment: You may want to review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718814/how-to-draw-ggmap-with-two-different-administrative-boundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also set `group` within the aesthetics mappings of `geom_path`, not only `x` and `y`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
vie_map1 <- getData("GADM", country="VNM", level=1)
# trying URL 'http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/VNM_adm1.rds'
# Content type '' length 2765340 bytes (2.6 MB)
# downloaded 2.6 MB
vie_map <- fortify(vie_map1, region = "ID_1")
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = vie_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey90") +
  geom_path(data = vie_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = "blue") + 
  theme_bw()
```